# 52% of people want to ban smoking Use the normal approximation to estimate that over half of a sample size $n$ support the the ban

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

52% of people want to ban smoking.

Use the normal approximation to estimate that more than half of a given  sample size $n$ support the the ban.

q=1-0.52=0.48

For $n=11, 101, 1001$

Are these steps correct:

1.) Finding the mean (p*n)

2.) multiplying by q (p*n*q), and taking the square root $\sqrt(pqn)$ to find std. dev.

3.)Now we want P(X$\ge$5.5)  (5.5 is half or more of our sample size) and we need to subtract 0.5 I believe?

Assuming these steps are correct, what's next?

Answer (score 1):

To find expressions like $P(X\geq x)$ where $X$ has normal distribution observe that $$P(X\geq x)=P(\sigma U+\mu\geq x)=P\left(U\geq\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$
where $U$ has standard normal distribution.

So actually for $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$:$$P(X\geq x)=1-\Phi\left(z\right)$$

You can find this $z$ by substituting.

From here [tables](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution-table.html) come in.

Also think of $\Phi(z_a)=a$ in your [former question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1799408/75923)

Comment: Thanks again! You've been a great help in tacking these problems!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: This might be overreaching, but do you mind helping me with another question I've posted?

Comment: I do not make any promises; too risky:-). Btw, where is it?

Comment: here it is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799525/2-cards-are-picked-from-a-deck-without-replacement-let-x-number-of-aces-and-y